# Bringing laptop with US keyboard layout back into the UK

Tags: customs-and-immigration, electronic-items

I will be visiting the US and will be taking my work laptop with a US keyboard layout. In the past, I have had trouble reentering the UK because the laptop looked like it was bought in the US and I was challenged at customs. Is it possible to obtain paperwork to make the reentry easier?

Comment: Not long ago I bought a laptop in the US which had the Euro symbol and AltGr keys, neither of which are present on US keyboards. I wouldn't have expected to have similar trouble if I traveled to the EU with it, so +1 for you.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to worry over this. Recently I flew from the UK to the US and back with a laptop having a Hebrew layout and no one even bat an eyelid.

Comment: Some countries' Customs used to let you register high value goods, but I haven't been able to find anything for the UK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original invoice or receipt showing that you or your company purchased it in the UK would be best. This way you can prove the laptop is [personal belongings you originally owned in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/overview) and thus exempt from duty and Import VAT.

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have the original documents. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe you still have the warranty receipt? That might work

Comment: Have your company prepare a paper that lists the computer, asset number, serial number etc. Does the UK have the same type of certification as a US notary public? Or put it in a sealed envelope, mail it (to get a dated postmark) to yourself, and bring it with you. Any questions, have them open it!

Comment: @TillHoffmann is it even a current production model? If not things become a lot easier... I've had questions raised about cameras a few times, until I pointed out they were 5 years old and no longer being made :)

Comment: @jwenting, good point. The machine is about five years old.

Comment: Then it will probably show a fair bit of wear & tear. It will certainly no longer have  that lovely "new laptop smell" ;-)